# Connect to a secure web-service using Python, SOAP and a .pfx Certificate?

Tags: python, web-services, soap, ssl, pfx

I need to connect to a secure web-service (https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeConsultaDest/NFeConsultaDest.asmx) using a .pfx certificate. I already tried every single example and python library I could find (suds, soappy, etc), and saw some stackoverflow answers too, but with no success....

Do I need to convert the certificate? If so, how?
Which library should I use?

Can someone post some code?

Thank you!